# Structring data flow in GAE without using globals

Tags: python, google-app-engine, global-variables

I am setting up an app in GAE. The app relies on up to three successive AJAX calls from the client that produces an individual string in each request. I would like to retain and combine the data on the server side in order to perform some more parsing on it.

I have been told that using global variables is really really bad, but I'm not sure how I would structure this flow without using globals to combine the data. Any suggestions? I don't want to do one single AJAX call because I would like to continue to update the user as to the progress. Abstractly it looks something like this-

```
finalData = ""

class func1(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        func1data = some.command()
        global finalData
        finalData += func1data


class func2(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        func2data = some.command()
        global finalData
        finalData += func2data


class func3(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        func3data = some.command()
        global finalData
        finalData += func3data
```

Comment: In the GAE python server, globals can be problematic in that they are somewhat persistent. The global value can persist even after the session closes. So a new user could perhaps get some other user's global data. Annoying...  The answer below is the best bet. Datastore/Memcache.

Answer (score 1):

It's a terrible idea, as in, it won't work.  Or worse, it might appear to work sometimes when your requests happen to hit the same instance, but it won't work otherwise.

Store the data in an entity in the the datastore/memcache (if you use ndb it'll automatically be put in memcache), and use a get() to fetch the data on each successive request.

Alternatives are to use sessions, or return the data in a cookie to the client so it's sent back to the server with the next request (though that would insecurely allow the client to modify the value).